# indexing two keys in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that I need to efficiently subset based on two columns. 
Specifically, I want to subset to all rows that do **not** contain a 
particular value for either column.

E.g., given the table below I want to exclude rows with 3, and get the result below:

```
exclude <- 3

tbl <- data.table(A = 1:4, B = 3:6)
tbl
   A B
1: 1 3
2: 2 4
3: 3 5
4: 4 6

desired_result <- data.table(A = c(2,4), B = c(4,6))
desired_result
   A B
1: 2 4
2: 4 6
```

It seems like you can't use keys to exclude items, as in below:

```
setkey(tbl, A, B)
tbl[!.(exclude, exclude)]
```

I've also tried something like this, but this only returns rows where A=B.

```
nums <- 1:6
include <- nums[nums != exclude]

setkey(tbl, A, B)
tbl[.(include, include)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: The "not-join" prefix (`!`) acts by the same logic as the usual join. It will only ignore rows that have *both* value matching at the same time, e.g., `tbl[!J(3, 5)]` will remove the third row, cause *both* terms were satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to keep row 3. I should add that this does what I want but it's just a lot lower than using keys: tbl[A != exclude & B != exclude]

Comment: Perhaps `tbl[!.(3), on = 'A'][!.(3), on = 'B']` if you want to use joins, but regular `tbl[A != 3 & B != 3]` is what I'd normally go with (fwiw some internal optimizing will automatically happen when you use the common sense syntax).